# Converting from decimals to roman numerals

Tags: javascript, interview-questions, converting, roman-numerals

I've submitted the following code for a job interview, and I wanna know if there is anything I can improve on it, or better ways to do the same thing.

```
const algarismsMap = {
    1 : {
        1 : 'I',
        4 : 'IV',
        5 : 'V',
        9 : 'IX'
    },
    1e1 : {
        1 : 'X',
        4 : 'XL',
        5 : 'L',
        9 : 'XC'
    },
    1e2 : {
        1 : 'C',
        4 : 'CD',
        5 : 'D',
        9 : 'CM'
    },
    1e3: {
        1 : "I\u0305",
        4 : 'I\u0305V\u0305',
        5 : 'V\u0305',
        9 : 'I\u0305X\u0305'
    },
    1e4: {
        1 : "X\u0305",
        4 : 'X\u0305L\u0305',
        5 : 'L\u0305',
        9 : 'X\u0305C\u0305'
    },
    1e5 : {
        1 : "C\u0305",
        4 : 'C\u0305D\u0305',
        5 : 'D\u0305',
        9 : 'C\u0305M\u0305'
    }
}

const divisors = Object.keys( algarismsMap ).reverse()

const romanizeNumber = module.exports = function( n ) {

    // not throwing an error because this can happen while recursing
    if ( n <= 0 ) {
        return ''
    }

    // welp, for numbers greater than 3999999 we break roman rules of not repeating the same algarism more than 3 times, 
    //   or we need to add more dashes, which is not really documented, at least I could not find some reliable source about it. 
    if ( n >= 4e6 ) {
        throw new Error( 'The max supported number to be converted is 3999999' )
    }

    let romanizedNumber = ''

    // Some special cases for the M algarism.
    if ( n >= 1e3 && n <= 3999 ||  n >= 1e6 && n <= 3999999 ) {

        romanizedNumber += ( n >= 1e6 ? 'M\u0305' : 'M' ).repeat( n / (n >= 1e6 ? 1e6 : 1e3 ) )
        romanizedNumber += romanizeNumber( n % (n >= 1e6 ? 1e6 : 1e3 ) )

    } else {

        for ( let i = 0; i < divisors.length; i++ ) {

            const currDivisor = divisors[i]|0
            const currDivisorInfo = algarismsMap[currDivisor]

            const internalDivisors = Object.keys( currDivisorInfo ).reverse()

            // The number is not divisible by this one, keep going (we could just check if n < currDivisor duh)
            if ( n % currDivisor === n ) {
                continue
            }

            for ( let k = 0; k < internalDivisors.length; k++ ) {

                const currInternalDivisor = internalDivisors[k]|0
                const currInternalDivisorAlgarism = currDivisorInfo[currInternalDivisor]

                if ( n >= currInternalDivisor * currDivisor ) {

                    // the 1 check here is basically for the same motive than the 'M' check above.
                    romanizedNumber += currInternalDivisor === 1 ? currInternalDivisorAlgarism.repeat( n / currDivisor ) : currInternalDivisorAlgarism

                    romanizedNumber += romanizeNumber( n % (currInternalDivisor * currDivisor) )

                    return romanizedNumber
                }
            }
        }

    }

    return romanizedNumber
}
```

The `\u0305` is the unicode for the combining overline character: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overline

Comment: Semicolons are missing all over the place -- a habit that is a great source of bugs especially when something is *maintaining* this code.
I am not a JS guy, could you tell what is the `... = internalDivisors[k]|0` idiom?

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko Almost all bitwise operators on Javascript work only with 32 signed integers, and since by default, all numbers in Javascript are 64 bits floats, doing the `OR 0` basically converts the number to int. 

Semicolons are _mostly_ optional, I'm not using them anymore. https://mislav.net/2010/05/semicolons/

Comment: Thanks for explaining the `x|0` idiom! Good to know. As far as the semicolons go, it's your choice but many devs including me find it a gate  to bugs hard to detect. In other words `The only real pitfall when coding without semicolons` which is mentioned in the post you shared, is a big deal, and the prepend next line with `;` is a dirty hack. The `“everybody else is doing it”` phrase *is* a real argument, if everyone uses the semicolons, not using them becomes a risk when it comes to maintenance -- as a tech lead I would enforce the semicolons.

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko I understand, but I'm doing it only on personal projects. So no worries there. Even the `|0` I would not do in a project with many other people, since some would not understand it, and also because of the confusion it could cause (it's not rounding the number for example, but truncating it).

Comment: As I said, it's your call -- that's why I am not posing an answer, but a comment. `I'm doing it only on personal projects` is a common reasoning, but as soon as you delegate maintenance to someone else you may get cursed for that decision.

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko Thanks for supporting semi-colons in JS! :) Call me old-school, but I tend to insist on them too

Comment: Haven't had time to really review this, so just two things that stand out: 1) The explanation for `\u0305` should probably be in the code too, and 2) you're fond of the scientific number notation like `4e6` yet you also have to write `3999999` in the comment and error message – I'd define `3999999` as a `MAX_INPUT` constant or something, and stick to using decimals. To me it's just easier than doing the (admittedly simple) conversion in my head. You're already dealing with roman and decimal notation - I'd rather not add another on top of that.

Comment: You write 4000 as  I̅V̅ instead of MV̅ for consistency. But why do you write 6000 as V̅M instead of V̅ I̅? To me, the latter seems more consistent: a decimal digit is either completely converted to a vinculum or it isn't, but not half-half.

Answer (score 3):

- I would define a constant `overline="\u0305"` and then use interpolation further down: `` 4 : `C${overline}D#{overline}`, ``, it might even make sense to define `overlineD` and `overlineC` constants. An alternative might be to create an `overline` method and write something like `4: overline('CD')` or even a tagged template literal (`` 4: overline`CD` ``) if you want to impress.
- `Object.keys( algarismsMap ).reverse()`: The order of keys in a hash is not guaranteed, it can vary depending on the implementation and if keys have been deleted, etc. If you need order you should use an array. Also rather than reversing just define it backwards.
- Rather than `if {...} else [lots of code]` I find it better to use an early return `if {...; return; } [lots of code]`
- One of the biggest thing to me is the lack of tests.  I would expect to see something in an interview assignment, it doesn't have to use a framework, I would be fine with something like:

  ```
  function test(number, roman) {
    if (romanizeNumber(number) !== roman)
      console.error(`Failed! ${number} should be ${roman} but was ${romanizeNumber(number)}`);
  }
  test(10, 'X');
  test(11, 'XI');
  ...
  ```

Comment: About the lack of tests, the assignment platform were this was submitted had automated testing already (https://www.hackerrank.com).

Answer (score 3):

Short review;

- I think you mean `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorism`, not algarism? I would use the correct name in that case, and personally I would even put a link to the wikipedia article for people (the vast majority I assume) who have never heard about Algorisms before
- I would call `Object.keys( algarismsMap ).`**sort()**`.reverse()`, making sure of the sort order
- This statement annoys me tremendously as a reviewer:

  `if ( n >= 1e3 && n <= 3999 ||  n >= 1e6 && n <= 3999999 )`

  Either go for

  `if ( n >= 1e3 && n < 4e3 ||  n >= 1e6 && n <= 4e6 )`

  or

  `if ( n >= 1000 && n < 4000 ||  n >= 1000000 && n <= 4000000 )`

  mixing those 2 constant styles just makes my brain go 'wot?' To keep it simple, I would go with the first approach.

Answer (score 1):

**General style**

- As this is an interview submission, I recommend a conservative coding style including semicolons.
- Mixing decimal and exponential notation for number literals is inconsistent.
- Mixing `""` and `''` without need is somewhat irritating.
- `+string` is more idiomatic and robust compared to the bitwise `string|0` for integer string to number conversion.
- `for (let divisor of divisors) { ... }` is more succint than `for (let i = 0; i < divisors.length; i++) { let divisor = divisors[i]; ... }`
- Catching and handling corner cases such as `if ( n % divisor === n ) continue;` early at the beginning of the loop body improves readability somewhat.
- I propose renaming

  - `algarismsMap` to `algarisms` - appending type information such as 'Array' or 'Map' rarely improves readability.
  - `algarisms` to `symbols` - algarism is exotic, symbol is a much more common term.
  - `currDivisor` to `divisor` - adding 'curr' and similar prefixes to loop iterators is noisy.
  - `internalDivisor` to `digit` - as it is more specific.

**Error handling**

This is inconsistent:

```
// not throwing an error because this can happen while recursing
if ( n <= 0 ) {
    return ''
}

if ( n >= 4e6 ) {
    throw new Error( 'The max supported number to be converted is 3999999' )
}
```

You throw an error when the input is too large, but not when it is too small. Also, instead of throwing an `Error` you could throw the more descriptive `RangeError`

**Comments**

While you include inline comments adressing implementation details, your interview submission is completely lacking in [documentation style comments](https://esdoc.org/manual/usage/tags.html).

Regarding your inline comments:

```
// The number is not divisible by this one, keep going (we could just check if n < currDivisor duh)
```

Why don't you use `n < currDivisor` then?

```
// welp, for numbers greater than 3999999 we break roman rules of not repeating the same algarism more than 3 times,
// or we need to add more dashes, which is not really documented, at least I could not find some reliable source about it.
```

Actually, you don't repeat symbols more than three times but throw an `Error`. This comment seems outdated. Also, using colloquial terms such as duh, welp and emoticons  in comments feels somewhat out of place in a professional setting (assuming you included them in your interview submission and not just for us reviewers).

```
// the 1 check here is basically for the same motive than the 'M' check above.
```

Since you never state the motive for the 'M' check, this comment is somewhat unhelpful.

**Data structures**

Your `algarismsMap` is a specialised, repetitive datastructure. It cannot be reused, as its structure seems to have explicitly been chosen to fit the needs of the `romanizeNumber` function.

However, you still need to perform key extraction and reversal

```
const internalDivisors = Object.keys( currDivisorInfo ).reverse()
```

as well as string to number conversion

```
const currInternalDivisor = currInternalDivisor|0
```

in order to extract the digits. This makes your code more complicated than necessary and less robust, as you rely on the [unspecified `Object.keys()` enumeration order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38218582/1647737).

Also, you still need to hardcode some data within the `romanizeNumber` function:

```
romanizedNumber += ( n >= 1e6 ? 'M\u0305' : 'M' ).repeat( n / (n >= 1e6 ? 1e6 : 1e3 ) )
```

While you can't avoid handling these special cases somehow, you could still avoid redundant definition of roman symbols.

**Design**

Your monolithic, recursive `romanizeNumber` function is pretty complex and hard to read and understand. You can simplify your code by identifying sub-tasks and breaking it down into smaller, modular functions:

- splitDigits(n) - split a number into digits. This replaces the modulo operations all over the place such as `n % (currInternalDivisor * currDivisor)` as well as the whole recursion.
- romanizeDigit(digit, place) - convert a single digit. This basically replaces the inner loop over `internalDivisors` as well as the special vinculum handling.

We can also exploit the repetitive nature of digit conversion

```
1 - 10:     I II III IV V VI VII VIII IX X
10 - 100:   X XX XXX XL L LX LXX LXXX XC C
100 - 1000: C CC CCC CD D DC DCC DCCC DM M
```

and introduce a `lookup` table relating digits to symbols.

The broken-down, non-recursive, documented `romanizeNumber` could then be written as follows:

```
/**
 * Split positive integer n < 1e21 into digits.
 *
 * @param {number} n - positive integer < 1e21.
 * @return {number[]} digits starting with lowest position.
 */
function splitDigits(n) {
  return Array.from(String(n), Number);
}

/**
 * Symbols used by roman (vinculum) numerals in ascending order for non-vinculum or mixed-vinculum digits.
 */
const lower = ['I', 'V', 'X', 'L', 'C', 'D', 'M', 'V\u0305'];

/**
 * Symbols used by roman (vinculum) numerals in ascending order for entirely-vinculum digits.
 */
const upper = ['I\u0305', 'V\u0305', 'X\u0305', 'L\u0305', 'C\u0305', 'D\u0305', 'M\u0305'];

/**
 * Lookup map from decimal digits to roman symbol indices or offsets.
 * @example
 * lookup[4] // [0, 1] which corresponds to ['I', 'V']
 */
const lookup = [[], [0], [0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1], [1], [1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2], [2]];

/**
 * Convert decimal digit to roman numeral according to the digit's place value.
 * @example 
 * romanizeDigit(4, 1) // 'XL' since digit 4 at place 1 has place value 40
 *
 * @param {number} digit - digit from 0 - 9.
 * @param {number} place - place of digit.
 * @return {string} roman numeral with value digit × 10^place.
 */
function romanizeDigit(digit, place) {
  let vinculum = place > 3 || (place == 3 && (digit == 4 || digit == 9));
  if (vinculum) {
    return lookup[digit].map(i => upper[2 * (place - 3) + i]).join('');
  } else {
    return lookup[digit].map(i => lower[2 * place + i]).join('');
  }
}

/**
 * Convert positive integer to roman numeral.
 *
 * @param {number} n - integer in range [1, 3999999].
 * @return {string} roman numeral with value n.
 */
function romanizeNumber(n) {
  if (n < 1 || n > 3999999) throw RangeError('Only numbers between 1 and 3999999 supported');
  let digits = splitDigits(n);
  return digits.map((digit, i) => romanizeDigit(digit, digits.length - i - 1)).join('');
}
```